# Whats wrong with this?

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I know I'm not actively mining eth but I can't figure out whats wrong:

Found suitable OpenCL device [Turks ] with 2147483648 bytes of GPU memory
  m  19:19:56|main  Getting work package...
  m  19:19:57|main  Got work package: #e7978c4a
  i  19:19:57|openclminer0  set work; seed: #1261dfe1, target: #0000000225c1
  i  19:19:57|openclminer0  Initialising miner...
  m  19:19:57|main  Mining on PoWhash #e7978c4a : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:19:58|main  Mining on PoWhash #e7978c4a : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
Using platform: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Using device: Turks(OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1800.11))
  m  19:19:59|main  Mining on PoWhash #e7978c4a : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
Printing program log

Creating cache buffer
Creating DAG buffer
Allocating/mapping DAG buffer failed with: clCreateBuffer(-61). GPU can't allocate the DAG in a single chunk. Bailing.
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(-38)
  m  19:20:00|main  Mining on PoWhash #e7978c4a : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:20:01|main  Mining on PoWhash #e7978c4a : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:20:02|main  Mining on PoWhash #e7978c4a : 0.00MH/s [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
  m  19:20:02|main  Got work package: #a63450d5

Is my GPU not powerful enough?

Comment: Are you mining solo or in a pool? And what card do you use?

Comment: eth-eu.dwarfpool

Comment: AMD Radeon HD 6570 - I wouldn't be surprised if it isn't the right card. I'm VERY new to this, so any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMD Radeon HD 6570 video card doesn't have a GPU sufficient for mining Ethereum

Comment: Had a feeling......What would be good enough? What is it that I am looking for as far as specs?

Comment: Ethereum miners are optimized to run on AMD RX 480/580 but you can also use NVidia 1070/1080/1080Ti

Comment: I have always been partial to AMD technology. Is there a certain spec I should be looking for?

Comment: As far as i know those series are the only ones you can use. If you don't like AMD then you can use Nvidia GeForce 10xx series

Comment: Just keep in mind, all those cards are lately ridiculously priced because of huge demand. Nvidia 1080Ti that i could but for $649 in November, now costs $1049

Comment: I do like AMD, and I was just looking at the prices for the AMD 480/580 -- $600. With the 580, what could be expected as far as mining? how much eth/day would be about average? .25+-

Comment: @AceG you can take a look at whattomine.com - the profits vary daily based on ETH price and network difficulty. It will probably be around $2 per card per day with 580

Comment: I have taken a look at that and don't really understand it fully. I don't see a place to select the GPU.

Comment: I'm thinking of actually mining ETC.

Comment: At the top of the page there are a bunch of boxes for various gpus. Select one, put number of gpus, and click calculate